# Why does net.Conn.close() seem to be closing at the wrong time?

Tags: go, tcp

I'm trying to read and write some commands from a TCP client. I want to close a connection after the last function has been executed but for some reason, it seems like the server disconnects the connection in the middle of the function even when explicitly placed afterward.

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "log"
        "net"
        "strconv"
        "strings"
        "time"
    )
    
    
    
    func main() {
        listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Print(err)
            }
            go handleConn(conn)
            conn.Close()
        }
    
    }
    
    func handleConn(someconnection net.Conn) {
        func1(someconnection)
        func2(someconnection) //connection drops in the middle of executing this part
    }
func func2(someconnection net.Conn) {

    //send message(a string)
    _, err := io.WriteString(someconnection, dosomething)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //await reply
    //send another message
    _, err = io.WriteString(someconnection, dosomething)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
   //await reply

    //send another message, connection tends to close somewhere here
    _, err = io.WriteString(someconnection, dosomething)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //await,send
    _, err = io.WriteString(someconnection, do something)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //await, read and print message
    c := bufio.NewReader(someconnection)
    buff1 := make([]byte, maxclientmessagelength)
    buff1, err = c.ReadBytes(delimiter)

    fmt.Printf("\n%s\n", buff1)

    _, err = io.WriteString(someconnection, dosomething)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

That means the client trying to communicate backward simply isn't able to communicate but the program runs to the end.

## Update 1:

Made some progress by placing the deferred close statement to when the connection was first acquired.

```
func main() {
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    go handleConn(conn)
}}
```

Now it doesn't necessarily close within the second I hope it to close but at least it now runs all the way through.

Comment: You can close the connection inside handleConn

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj tried this. Problem persists but at least it closes the connection at the right time occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goroutines are asynchronous so after calling handleConn here:

```
go handleConn(conn)
conn.Close()
```

the main function continues to execute and closes the connection.
Try just calling the handleConn function regularly (without the `go`).

Comment: Or move the `conn.Close()` to the last line of `handleConn` so you may have multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: @DylanReimerink yep. i was about to edit the answer because i just noticed the call is inside a for loop and maybe OP wants all of them to be concurrent

Comment: @DylanReimerink yes I was planning on running multiple concurrent connections but for now, I'm trying to test a single one.

Comment: @Fedex7501 the problem still persists for some reason.

Comment: @Fedex7501 holdup... It worked right once but after calling the client again it failed. So while it's working now it seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: that seems much harder to diagnose tbh

Comment: @Fedex7501 could it be timing and timeout-related? The first func makes use of NewReader but it didn't seem to be an issue in this. Where server tends to cutoff is somewhere in the second func.

Answer (score 1):

The `conn.Close` needs to de done AFTER `handleConn` has done its work. You could communicate the back to the main thread using channels but that would be too complex (and also block execution of main thread). This is how it should be done

```
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
        // REMOVE BELOW LINE
        // conn.Close()
    }
}
```

Add `conn.Close` inside `handleConn`

```
func handleConn(someconnection net.Conn) {
    // ADD BELOW LINE
    defer someconnection.Close()
    func1(someconnection)
    func2(someconnection)
}
```

This makes sure `conn.Close` is called AFTER `func1` and `func2` are done executing